# Moving a database offsite while using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

An app I'm currently working on uses Entity Framework 4 which connects to a database on the local network.  We now need this database to be hosted on a server at a different location.  Obviously our client apps (Windows Forms) will still need to access the data.  Using a VPN would be the easiest, but that is not an option in this case.  With that said, what are my options?  Is there a way I can expose the entity data model via web services that would require minimal rework of the client application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Research into WCF Data Services: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668794.aspx

And have a quick read through this, to get an idea of how easy it is to setup wrapper service for EF. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/21/using-wcf-data-services-with-entity-framework-4-1-and-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In short; take a look at WCF Services, but make sure you don't expose `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable` instances via your service.

The long rambling, possibly beer related version:

Without knowing the details of your application architecture it's hard to give a concrete answer.

If you have built the application on a number of services classes inside your existing app you may be able to simply expose those services directly via some form of web service. However, you must be careful if you have passed instances of `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable` across your service boundaries. If you have you may find that porting to webservices causes very large amounts or data being passed over the network or you may see N+1 problems and the app may start to become very 'chatty'.

An alterative may be to give your users direct access to your database with a limited user. This is always something I'm nervous of, especially if this is a public application. In this case you have to make sure that the sql user that you give them has the fewest and least permissions you can possibly get away with.

You also need to be aware that moving off your local network will incur much larger latency when talking to your database. Depending on how your app is coded you may start to see the UI locking or hanging while the network round trip takes place.

If you have coded your app well to begin with splitting out your db access into services, will at the very least be tricky (unless your app is very simple).